# How do I download and set up the standard library for Agda in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, agda

I have installed and been able to use Agda on my Ubuntu system via the emacs editor, and all seems good so far.

However, I am unable to install and set up the standard library for it.

Following this: https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1/getting-started/installation.html I have tried

```
apt-get install agda-stdlib
```

which worked, but then I tried following this: https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools/package-system.html
and the directory where apt-get seemed to install agda-stdlib does not contain a library file 
**standard-library.agda-lib**, only the following

> Algebra            Function         IO.agda           Relation
>   Algebra.agda       Function.agda    IO.agdai          Size.agda
>   Algebra.agdai      Function.agdai   Level.agda        Size.agdai
>   Category           index.agda       Level.agdai       Strict.agda
>   Coinduction.agda   Induction        Record.agda       Strict.agdai
>   Coinduction.agdai  Induction.agda   Record.agdai      Universe.agda
>   Data               Induction.agdai  Reflection.agda   Universe.agdai
>   Foreign            IO               Reflection.agdai

What am I missing and how should I proceed?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you on? What is the output of `agda --version`?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04.2 and the Agda version 2.6.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The versions of both Agda and the standard library in the Ubuntu package manager are quite outdated. So you should not mix a version of Agda installed via Cabal or Stack with a version of the standard library installed via Ubuntu's package manager. Instead, you can find the right version of the standard library for your version of Agda on https://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=Libraries.StandardLibrary. Specifically, for Agda 2.6.1 you need the standard library version 1.3, which you can install from Github:

```
git clone https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib.git
git checkout tags/v1.3
```

and then follow the instructions at https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tools/package-system.html to make sure Agda can find the installation.

Comment: Thank you, there was indeed a problem with the package from the ubuntu package manager. Installing according to this https://github.com/agda/agda-stdlib/blob/master/notes/installation-guide.md seemed to have solved the issue.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question about the missing `standard-library.agda-lib` file in the ubuntu package. Is that package broken?